# Personal remark environment after an equation

Tags: equations, environments

I have the following remark environment:

```
\newenvironment{rem}[1][]{%
\vspace{8pt}\small%
\begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\parindent}%
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{\parindent}}%
      \item[]%
}{%
\end{list}\vspace{8pt}}%
```

When used just after an equation, the separating vertical space shall be a bit to large. Is there a way to test if the previous line is an equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\addvspace{<dimen>}` will check the magnitude of the previous `vspace` and insert (if necessary) the amount of space needed to result in a final space that is the larger of the two specified dimensions, not their sum.

`\addvspace` must be used in vertical mode, so if the current mode isn't clear,
use `\par\addvspace`.

Comment: Now that I coming back to reality, it is probably recommended to locally set up the `\topsep` argument of the list embedded in the `rem` environment rather than adding two `\vspace` or `\addvspace` that are, in a sense, already part of the `\topsep` length.